# Jquery dataformat number tables not working when mobile version

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have problem when using format number. In normal resolution Jquery format number is working but on mobile it is not working.

on normal resolution:
[image]

on mobile:

[image]

this is my code :

```
{ 
   "data": "adult_single_price", 
   "class":"text-right",
   "render": function( data, type, full ) {
      return formatNumber(data);                                       
   },  
   "width": "10%",
   "name": "view_tour.adult_single_price"                                            
},
```

Need help understanding the problem.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried with mobile on landscape mode?

Comment: I have tried but still not working